# Angular 5 - Mat-tab method called inside *ngFor getting executed mutilple times

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular5, ng-template

I have doubt as when i am calling a function inside *ngFor , it is getting executed multiple times , number more than the elements in the array **tabsName** . Here is the code below :

```
     <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab  *ngFor="let tab of tabsName">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          {{getTabName(tab)}}
          <span class="badge">{{getTabCount(tab)}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <div *ngTemplateOutlet="comments"></div>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>  


    <ng-template #comments>
      <div class="col-sm-9 jj-pad-0">Deep</div>
</ng-template>
```

After implementing all the lifecycle hooks of a component , got to know that some life cycle hooks methods are getting called again and again.

I wanted to know is this the right behaviour or not?

Properties of tabsName are name and count. Name and count i am getting from the service making a rest call.

tabsName : [{name:'tab1',count:'2'},{name:'tab2',count:'1'}]

Below is the ts file .

```
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tabsName: any;
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Output() tabSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private service: SomeService) {

  }

getTabName(tab): string {

    return this.service.configData[tab]['UILabel'];
  }

  getTabCount(tab): number {
    if (this.service.dataMap) {
      return this.service.dataMap.get(this.service.configData[tab]['dataType']).data.length;
    }
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    this.tabSelected.emit(event);
  }

}
```

Comment: Function calls bounded to the template in an expression will be executed every time that change detection is performed. So thats the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using `*ngFor` seems wrong to me, it should be `{{ tab.getTabName }}` and
`{{ tab.getTabCount }}` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . As per my requirement , i have to pass the tab in inside getTabCount and getTabName functions like getTabCount(tab1) or getTabCount(tab2) and get the count for that particular tab. Can you suggest how can i achieve that?

Comment: Can you edit the question and also add the necessary .ts file and properties related to tabsName? And also from where you are getting getTabCount, getTabName.

Comment: I have updated the question , hope it helps now . Kindly let me know if you still have any doubts.